# Chladni Plate Mathematics

Tags: waves, frequency, resonance, vibrations

I am a high school student doing an IB Extended Essay investigation concerning the resonant frequencies of [Chladni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Chladni) plates of differing materials and sizes.  Would someone please explain the definition of radial and diametric nodes ($n$ and $m$), and how to determine them? In addition, would someone be willing to provide a derivation of [Chladni's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chladni's_law) $$f \sim (m + 2n)^2?$$

Here is a link with related mathematical resources:
http://www.nhn.ou.edu/~johnson/Education/Juniorlab/Chladni/2001-ChladniPlates-CurtisParry.pdf

Comment: Related: http://motls.blogspot.cz/2013/04/ernst-chladni-anniversary.html