# What 2d shapes would have the most resonant frequencies?

Tags: acoustics, resonance

A square Chladni plate has a handful of resonant frequencies in the audio range. If you wanted to make a plate with very many (infinite?) resonant frequencies, what shape would be best?

You wouldn't see any cool patterns because there wouldn't be any powerful resonances.

Maybe the classic guitar/violin shape is actually the best you can do.

I guess cutting holes in the shape is allowed, but only if necessary.

related:
[Theory behind patterns formed on Chladni plates?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/theory-behind-patterns-formed-on-chladni-plates)

[image: Chladni plate]

Comment: How fixed points can you have? (I'm assuming the hex nut in the middle is the only fixed point).

Comment: Yes. One fixed point.