# Chladni Plate subjected to different waves

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

A Chladni plate consists of a flat sheet of metal, usually circular or square, mounted on a central stalk to a sturdy base. When the plate is oscillating in a particular mode of vibration, the nodes and antinodes that are set up form complex but symmetrical patterns over its surface. If the Chladni plate is subjected to different types of waves such as triangle waves, square waves, or saw tooth waves, could that create enough tension in the plate causing it to shatter?

How can I calculate at what frequency the plate shatters?

Comment: Related: http://motls.blogspot.cz/2013/04/ernst-chladni-anniversary.html and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90021/2451

Comment: *How can I calculate at what frequency the plate shatters?* What would break the plate would be not so much frequency as the **amplitude**, much like a test bar (of steel, e.g.) ultimately break when the strain is too high.

Comment: The patterns you see are related to the "resonance" frequencies.  If you vibrate it off resonance you will get some other mess, the little beads will move around and not likely settle into the nodes.  As Gert stated, the amplitude is more likely to cause damage.