# Chladni Patterns (Length Factor)

Tags: waves, acoustics, resonance

I've recently been conducting experiments on the Chladni Plates, testing out how the length of a square Chladni plate (and consequently its area) affects the frequency at which each respective chladni pattern is formed.

The result shows that as the area of the plate decreases, the frequency at which each respective pattern is formed increases exponentially. However, after doing some research. Besides [Chladni's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chladni%27s_law):

$$f=C(m+2n)^{p}$$

No other equation, I've found really relates properties of the plates to the frequency at which certain patterns are formed. Furthermore, since both C and P are unknown except for objects such as bells, I am unable to use the Chladni Law.

My question is if anyone knows of a formula that can relate of them the frequency and dimensions of the chladni plate together, or if there even is one.

Comment: Related: http://motls.blogspot.cz/2013/04/ernst-chladni-anniversary.html and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78351/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90021/2451

Comment: These constants are numbers that depends on the stiffness of the plate and its density per unit area. Your relation was for round plates, where there are radial nodes and circular nodes, and a difference of approximately that factor 2.

Answer (score 0):

well if

f = frequency at which each respective pattern is formed

a = area of chladni plate

and your experiments show that **a ∝ f^n** then

**a = kf^n** where k is a constant that can be found through repeated experiments.

This could either be completely wrong or scientifically sound